# "for in" protocol in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that save data.
Every time I extract data, I call its method, and extract only one data at a time.
So I need a loop to extract.
Like this:

```
while (dataNumber == 0) {
    id res = [testClass numericFromColumnBy_Cid:columnID];
}
```

But I want it to support Objective-C's "for in" loop, just like NSArray.

```
for (NSString *str in NSArray) {};
```

How do I set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with [NSFastEnumeration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfastenumeration).

Example from [Fast Enumeration, part 1](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/fast-enumeration-part-1/):

```
@interface Orchestra : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
- (void) addMusician: (Musician *) musician;
@end // Orchestra
```

And add the required method, which just turns around and passes the arguments through to the array:

```
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState *) enumerationState
                                   objects: (id __unsafe_unretained []) buffer
                                     count: (NSUInteger) len {
    return [_members countByEnumeratingWithState: enumerationState
                     objects: buffer
                     count: len];
} // countByEnumeratingWithState
```

For the curious, [Mike Ash has a fantastic blog post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html) where he dives into the internals, providing several reference implementations of NSFastEnumeration.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement that method, if I doesn't have enumeratable member in class